# Sort a List(Of IO.FileInfo) by file-extension

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, sorting, io

I have a directory with files with these filenames:

```
12.mp4
34.wmv
56.ogm
78.avi
90.m4v
```

In my application I list the files of the directory into a List(Of File.Info) which is indexed as default:

```
FileList.Item(0).Name = 12.mp4
FileList.Item(1).Name = 34.wmv
FileList.Item(2).Name = 56.ogm
FileList.Item(3).Name = 78.avi
FileList.Item(4).Name = 90.m4v
```

But I need to process the files by the file-extension sorted in ascending mode, so this is the Item-indexation I need:

```
FileList.Item(0).Name = 78.avi
FileList.Item(1).Name = 90.m4v
FileList.Item(2).Name = 12.mp4
FileList.Item(3).Name = 56.ogm
FileList.Item(4).Name = 34.wmv
```

How I can sort the List like that in VB.NET or C#?

Comment: Please choose a language. I assume you're not going to build a library of a _different_ language just for this method. And if you already have mixed-language libraries, then the language of the code should not be the decider in where it goes.

Comment: _'Maybe I prefer information to do it using LINQ to gain speed against looping the List'_ As if Linq doesn't loop through the list? Linq is known for a few things, speed over native constructs certainly isn't one of them.

Comment: @Grant Thomas I could translate C# example to VB and vicevers that's why I said that (I think I'm free to ask a solution for both languages without prejudices.), thanks for comment.

Comment: And so it's just a pity for the rest of those users that can't, I understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this is a `List(Of`[`FileInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx)`)`, you could use:

```
FileList.Sort(Function(fi1,fi2) return fi1.Extension.CompareTo(fi2.Extension))
```

Note that a LINQ solution would potentially be nicer if you can do this sort when you build your `FileInfo` list, ie:

```
Dim FileList = theDirectoryInfo.GetFiles().OrderBy(Function(f) f.Extension).ToList()
```

However, if the list already is built, sorting in place will potentially be cleaner than using LINQ to rebuild the list then reassign.

Comment: thanks for your answer, can you tell me which beneffits have using sort method than orderby if any?

Comment: @ElektroHacker Edited to discuss.  WIth OrderBy, if you already have the `List(Of T)`, you'll have to create a new `IEnumerable(Of T)`, then convert it to a list, then reassign.  Sorting in place avoids that.  If you do the sort *when you build the list originally*, then LINQ is potentially cleaner (see my edit for that code)

Answer (score 6):

```
var sorted = FileList.OrderBy(f => f.Extension);
```

Comment: He wants `FileList` sorted, so you'd need to use `ToList()` and reassign (which is why I just sorted in place).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public class ExtComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        //return Path.GetExtension(x).CompareTo(Path.GetExtension(y)); or
        return System.String.Compare(Path.GetExtension(x), Path.GetExtension(y), System.StringComparison.Ordinal);
    }
}
```

Use: 
    MyList.Sort(new ExtComparer ());